# Unwanted vertical line in longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, ltxtable

I am trying to build a table using longtable and `tabularx` with the ltxtable.
For some weird reason, unwanted vertical lines appear on the first row.
This is my `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\begin{document}
  \LTXtable{\linewidth}{table.tex}
\end{document}
```

This is `table.tex`:

```
\small
\begin{longtable}{| p{0.7cm} | X |}\label{tab:evaluation_survey}
\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{e.1)} &  \textbf{Question}:\\
\cline{2-2}
& \textbf{Answers}: \\ \hline
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{e.2)} &  \textbf{Question}: \\
\cline{2-2} 
& \textbf{Answers}:  \\ \hline
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{e.3)} &  \textbf{Question}: \\ 
\cline{2-2} 
& \textbf{Answers}: \\ \hline
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{e.4)} &  \textbf{Question}:\\ 
\cline{2-2} 
& \textbf{Answers}: \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

And this is what appears:
[image]

Edit: if I remove the `\\` before the first `\hline` I receive `\noalign` and `\omit` errors

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Remove the first `\\ ` before `\hline`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please merge bot code snippets into complete document, which we can copy and compile.

Comment: @Zarko: `ltxtable` needs the table in an extra file. So the document is complete with the two files. The user could use `filecontents` to generate it from `main.tex`. Or you could copy both files. But you cannot replace `\LTXtable{…}{…}` by the code from `table.tex`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, ups, I overlooked `ltxtable` ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from the usage of `\label{}` inside the table. Normally you use `\label{}` after the caption in the floating environment. I don't know LTXtable so I can't provide the correct placement for the `\label{}` but just to solve the issue there are several ways here (like placing the `\label{}` inside one of the existing rows etc.). One of this ways would be to use a `\noalign{}`:

Change the content of table.tex to:

```
\small
\begin{longtable}{| p{0.7cm} | X |}\noalign{\label{tab:evaluation_survey}}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{e.1)} &  \textbf{Question}:\\
\cline{2-2}
& \textbf{Answers}: \\ \hline
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{e.2)} &  \textbf{Question}: \\
\cline{2-2} 
& \textbf{Answers}:  \\ \hline
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{e.3)} &  \textbf{Question}: \\ 
\cline{2-2} 
& \textbf{Answers}: \\ \hline
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{e.4)} &  \textbf{Question}:\\ 
\cline{2-2} 
& \textbf{Answers}: \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this code, based on `ltablex`, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. I also redesigned the table, based on `hhline` and `makecell`  so the cells do not look as tight as  the default.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow, ltablex, hhline, makecell}
\keepXColumns
\setcellgapes{1ex}

\begin{document}

\small\setlength\doublerulesep{2ex}%
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.7cm} |X|}
\caption{A questions and answers table}\label{tab:evaluation_survey}\\[-1ex]
\endfirsthead
\hhline{~|-}
\multirow{2}{=}{e.1)} & \textbf{Question}:\\%
\hhline{~|-}
& \textbf{Answers}: \\
\hhline{~:=}
\multirow{2}{=}{e.2)} & \textbf{Question}: \\
\hhline{~|-}
& \textbf{Answers}: \\
\hhline{~:=}
\multirow{2}{=}{e.3)} & \textbf{Question}: \\
\hhline{~|-}
& \textbf{Answers}: \\
\hhline{~:=}
\multirow{2}{=}{e.4)} & \textbf{Question}:\\
\hhline{~|-}
& \textbf{Answers}: \\
\hhline{~|-}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]